# [Drupal][Google API] Error 403: SSL is required to perform this operation

Tags: ssl, drupal-7, google-api

This error is making me crazy.

I googled and It's due to a missing "s" in "https" but my code is correct, my endpoint has the "s" in url and above all, the same code works in another website not mine.

http://bidicotest.altervista.org/bidico/book/add

This is the website, try to search a book and the error will be shown on the upper side.

That's my code and I'm 100% sure it works

```
function get_remote_content($search_term)
{
    $api_end_point = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";

    $api_param = urlencode($search_term);

    //Chiamata api a google books
    $result = drupal_http_request($api_end_point . $api_param );

    //Se il codice è 200 (ok) o 304 (Not modified)
    if (in_array($result->code, array(200, 304))) {
        return print_book_matching_list($result->data);
    } else { //error
        return "<p>Si è verificato un errore: controllare la connessione.</p>";
    }
}
```

And it gives me:

> [request] => GET /books/v1/volumes?q=asd HTTP/1.0 User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/) Host: www.googleapis.com [data] => {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"sslRequired","message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}],"code":403,"message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}} [protocol] => HTTP/1.0 [status_message] => Forbidden [headers] => Array ( [cache-control] => private, max-age=0 [date] => Fri, 28 Aug 2015 08:28:11 GMT [accept-ranges] => none [server] => GSE [vary] => Origin,Accept-Encoding [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8 [expires] => Fri, 28 Aug 2015 08:28:11 GMT [x-content-type-options] => nosniff [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block ) [code] => 403 [error] => Forbidden

I've enabled s2s communications but nothing changed.

The code perfectly works locally.

I asked in the hosting company's forum but nobody knows.
I can't figure it out by myself and I'm asking your help.

Thanks in advance,
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

drupal_http_request uses a socket connection, not cURL.

My hosting company allows only cURL connections.

This did the trick: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/chr